# QGIS 3.16 Use change state of a checkbox as a trigger for updating another field

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, datetime, autofields

I want to record the date/time of field survey for features. This should **only be updated at the moment a checkbox value is ticked**.
Further edits would be needed to the record later, either in the field or later in the office, so I don't want to loose the field survey date.

date/time field is SurveyDate
Checkbox field is SurveyedYN. Value ticked=Y, value unticked=null

All the solutions I have seen so far will

1 - update the date/time  when any change is made in the record:

Using the form default value to set an expression for the Default Value to $now() and choosing the "apply default value on update" option.

2 - update the date/time when any change is made AND the checkbox is checked (from another similar question):

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

f1 = 'SurveyDate'
f2 = 'SurveyedYN'
e = QgsExpression("$now")

layer.startEditing()

for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    if feat[f2] is True:
        feat[f1] = e.evaluate()
        layer.updateFeature(feat)

layer.commitChanges()
```

So far the only answer I can come up with is not elegant. I would create a second field for the survey date that has no default value set and update the second from the first. This would over-write the original field, so any errors and I would loose the data.

I also need something that will work in the expression builder, as this has to go into Qfield for surveyors' mobile devices. So the code above wouldn't work anyway as its in the console

Update:
I managed a dirty fix. I set up a second checkbox field called "confirm". The datetime field will update to the current time if the SurveyYN is ticked AND the confirm is unticked. If both are ticked, the datetime will update to its current value.

It looks like this in the default value box for SurveyDate with "apply on update" switched on:

```
If ("SurveyedYN" = 'Y AND "confirm" = 'N', $now(), "SurveyDate")
```